# Crawl rule *://*/lists/* crawl rule

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, enterprise-search

what is purpose of below crawl rule in share point 2013 search service application , i have a publishing site collection and its web application deployed on port 443

Crawl Rule: *://*/lists/* crawl rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will include/exclude all the lists pages from the search. This regular expression defines that the url which contains "/lists/" should be included/excluded from the Crawling in search service.

You can get more reference from below links:

- http://sivarajan.me/post/How-to-crawl-the-specific-lists-in-SharePoint-foundation-2013
- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-crawl-rules-c2a2f9ff-f732-4e6f-a403-1c5ef963dc34?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US